# Requiring directive's controller from component return an empty controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

So I have been trying to figure this out for the past 4 hours. Basically I have a parent directive which is being dynamically compiled into DOM
And within it I have a component which is being transcluded

```
$compile('<edit-modal entry="entry" positions="positions" day="day" is-filled="isFilled" week-start-date="weekStartDate" available-tags="availableTags" minigrids="minigrids">' +
        '<ns-gap-requests gap="entry" minigrids="minigrids"></ns-gap-requests></edit-modal>')(scope);
```

Following is the component render in editModal html:

```
 <div id="gapRequestsBody" ng-if="onGapRequest" ng-transclude></div>
```

Following is my parent directive

```
 return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        transclude:"true",
        templateUrl: 'Scripts/NewScheduler/Templates/Modals/editModal.html',

        scope: {
            positions: '<',
            entry: '=',
            day: '<',
            weekStartDate: '<',
            availableTags: '<',
            minigrids: '<'
        },

        controller: ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.$parent.child = $scope;

            $scope.onGapRequest = false;
            $scope.changeToOnGapRequestPage = function() {
                $scope.onGapRequest = true;
            }
```

.....

Following is my child component:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('newScheduler').component('nsGapRequests',
        {
            require:{editModalCtrl : "^editModal"},
            bindings: {
                gap: "=",
                minigrids:"<"
            },
            templateUrl: "Scripts/NewScheduler/Templates/Modals/nsGapRequestsModal.html",
            controller: [function () {
                var self = this;

                self.$onInit = function() {
                    console.log(self);
                }

                console.log(self.gap);
                console.log(self.minigrids);

                if (!self.assignToOption) {
                    self.assignToOption = { chosenRequester: null };
                }

                self.requesters = self.minigrids.map(function (minigrid) {
                    return minigrid.gridRows;
                }).reduce(function(a, b) {
                    return a.concat(b);
                })
                    .map(function (gridRows) {
                    return gridRows.user;
                    })
                .filter(function (value, index, array) {
                    return array.indexOf(value) === index;
                })
                .filter(function(user) {
                    return self.gap.requests.indexOf(user.id) !== -1;
                    });

            }],
            controllerAs: "gapRequests"
        });
})();
```

But I cannot understand why I cannot access the parent controller:
[console log of the child component members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZvQH.png)

and for some reason editModalCtrl is empty (but it should not be!!!)

I would really appreciate if someone could help me on this. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller is actually not empty, you just didn't defined any property/method on it. You're working with `$scope` instead. Try adding some members and check:

```
controller: ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
    var self = this;
    self.someMember = true;
    self.someMethod = function() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh u are right. Thanks heaps. But one question though. I thought when you are sharing the directive's controller with another directive/component,you are actually sharing the scopes, isn't this true?.

Comment: No, unless you exposing it explicitly in some way. Also you could bind straight to controller instead of using $scope.